# Getting open dialog when trying to read XLSX

Tags: c#, xlsx

On my machine the following piece of codes reads my XLSX file located in my softwares program files correctly. However when i install it on a friends machine when the button is clicked that runs this piece of code it opens an open file dialog, almost like it cannot read the file. Does anybody have any ideas in terms of what is going wrong?

The code is:

```
Using fs As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "\DeliveryNoteTemplate.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
WBook = ExcelWorkbook.ReadXLSX(Application.StartupPath & "\DeliveryNoteTemplate.xlsx")
fs.Flush()
End Using
```

Thank you

Comment: The ExcelWorkbook class requires the interop assemblies be installed on the machine, which means having Excel installed on the machine.

Comment: Excel is installed on my friends machine, could it be because they are using an older version? :) thanks for the help btw

Comment: You should use the Open XML API unless you actually want the user to interact with the Excel UI. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/2.5.0

Comment: Hi we're using a different dll in order to open the file that allows you to open the file without having excel installed on the machine, it just seems strange as it is working on the one machine correctly but not the other.

Comment: @Emyr is correct. You should use OpenXml if you are just trying to manipulate the file and not use the Excel UI. The interop dll's can be fairly tricky to deal with and if it is a 3rd party dll, if it was free, it is probably crap. Go with OpenXml and save yourself a lot of pain and agony.